# How to stop the browser window from scrolling when I scroll a spark Datagrid in Flex 4?

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, browser, flex4

I have a spark DataGrid which has more rows than its size. I want to use the mouse scroll to scroll the DataGrid, but when I do, the whole browser window *also scrolls*.

Is there a way to stop the browser scrolling when I just want to scroll the DataGrid (or perhaps whenever the mouse is over the Flex application [which is embedded in an HTML page])? I'm thinking perhaps there's a javascript solution, I'm not sure.

Comment: As long as the Flash Player has focus; the browser window should not scroll.  Which browser are you having issues with?  Have you tested in other browsers?  Can you link to a sample?

Comment: in firefox even the flash player has focus the page scroll keeps working, you must try to set to some flash's object container ev.preventDefault() and .stopPropagation()

Comment: http://queirozf.com/home/lessonslearnt.php - click the search button. A datagrid will come up. I'm testing it on chrome. Will look at different browsers though. Just tested with Firefox, had the same issue.

Comment: @wes I've never run into that before.  Usually it is the browser that sends events to the Flash Player.  I'd be surprised if canceling the Flash Player event would affect browser behavior.

Comment: @Felipe Almeida Bizarre; I can't believe I've never run into that before.  I tested in Firefox and replicated the behavior you describe. I can understand why it is annoying.

Comment: it was introduced recently in firefox, for some usability reason, I guess, canceling the event should prevent the page from scrolling, btw

Comment: WHat do you mean cancelling the event? How do I go about doing that?

Comment: you would add a listener for MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL then in the handler you'd take the event that's passed in and call event.stopImmediatePropagation() or sometimes event.preventDefault() this does seem very odd though since that should just stop the propagating of the event upward through the display tree but that shouldn't necessarily affect the HTML/DOM outside of the flash player.  You may have to hack it with some javascript too (capturing the mouse wheel event between browsers varies). http://www.adomas.org/javascript-mouse-wheel/

Comment: I've stopped doing Flex stuff some time ago =P. But thanks for the input.That said, the ideas I had for using mouse wheel events in UI's are not dead yet =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to listen for scrolling event in your scrollable container (`TextArea`/`DataGrid`/whatever) and `event.stopPropagation()`

It is also a good idea not to stop event propagation when you are at top/bottom of your container, in that case user probably wants to scroll the outer container.

viz http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=events_08.html

Comment: Ha.. So long ago... I've since stopped using Flex altogether I'm afraid. But Thanks for the answer.. Are you sure it is 100%? If it is, I'll tick you up.

Comment: yeah, I am pretty sure sure this approach works :) I'm enjoying the dusk of this technology.